# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when i use pthreads on ubuntu

Tags: pthreads

I use pthreads on ubuntu to implement multithreaded matrix-vector multiplication, but the runtime reports an error Segmentation fault

```
#pragma comment(lib, "pthreadVC2.lib")
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

 /* Global variables */
int     thread_count = 8;
int     m, n;
double* A = NULL;
double* x = NULL;
double* y = NULL;

/* Serial functions */
void Usage(char* prog_name);
void Read_matrix(char* prompt, double A[], int m, int n);
void Read_vector(char* prompt, double x[], int n);
void Print_matrix(char* title, double A[], int m, int n);
void Print_vector(char* title, double y[], double m);

/* Parallel function */
void* Pth_mat_vect(void* rank);

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    long thread;
    pthread_t* thread_handles;
    thread_count = atoi(argv[1]);
    thread_handles = malloc(thread_count * sizeof(pthread_t));

    printf("Enter m and n\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

    A = malloc(m * n * sizeof(double));
    x = malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    y = malloc(m * sizeof(double));

    Read_matrix("Enter the matrix", A, m, n);
    Print_matrix("We read", A, m, n);

    Read_vector("Enter the vector", x, n);
    Print_vector("We read", x, n);

    for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL,
            Pth_mat_vect, (void*)thread);

    for (thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);

    Print_vector("The product is", y, m);

    free(A);
    free(x);
    free(y);

    return 0;
}  /* main */


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:    Read_matrix
 * Purpose:     Read in the matrix
 * In args:     prompt, m, n
 * Out arg:     A
 */
void Read_matrix(char* prompt, double A[], int m, int n) {
    int i, j;

    printf("%s\n", prompt);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%lf", &A[i * n + j]);
}  /* Read_matrix */


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:        Read_vector
 * Purpose:         Read in the vector x
 * In arg:          prompt, n
 * Out arg:         x
 */
void Read_vector(char* prompt, double x[], int n) {
    int   i;

    printf("%s\n", prompt);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%lf", &x[i]);
}  /* Read_vector */


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:       Pth_mat_vect
 * Purpose:        Multiply an mxn matrix by an nx1 column vector
 * In arg:         rank
 * Global in vars: A, x, m, n, thread_count
 * Global out var: y
 */
void* Pth_mat_vect(void* rank) {
    long my_rank = (long)rank;
    int i, j;
    int local_m = m / thread_count;
    int my_first_row = my_rank * local_m;
    int my_last_row = (my_rank + 1) * local_m - 1;

    for (i = my_first_row; i <= my_last_row; i++) {
        y[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            y[i] += A[i * n + j] * x[j];
    }

    return NULL;
}  /* Pth_mat_vect */


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:    Print_matrix
 * Purpose:     Print the matrix
 * In args:     title, A, m, n
 */
void Print_matrix(char* title, double A[], int m, int n) {
    int   i, j;

    printf("%s\n", title);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%4.1f ", A[i * n + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}  /* Print_matrix */


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function:    Print_vector
 * Purpose:     Print a vector
 * In args:     title, y, m
 */
void Print_vector(char* title, double y[], double m) {
    int   i;

    printf("%s\n", title);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        printf("%4.1f ", y[i]);
    printf("\n");
}  /* Print_vector */
```

This code is from *An Introduction to Parallel Programming*
I know this error seems to be related to memory, in fact the code runs without entering main().I tried some other people's methods, but none of them worked.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you run *without* pthreads?  That is, set `thread_count` to 1, and call `Pth_mat_vect((void*) 0)` explicitly.

Comment: Does the pthreads version work correctly when when the number of threads evenly divides the number of rows?

Comment: it still reported an error: Segmentation fault